# Why doesn't a for-loop iterate without compound assignment operators

Tags: swift, for-loop

I am trying to replace every character of source string with "". If I remove `+=` from my code, the for-loop iterates only once, and I can't seem to follow the logic behind this.

However, if I use `+=`, the for-loop iterates. Shouldn't iterations have equalled the number of characters in `stringExample`? I mean my understanding was always: "For every 'item' in 'items', execute this code."

```
let stringExample = "Hello, Playground"
var emptyString = ""

for _ in stringExample {

  emptyString = ""
}
print(emptyString)
```

My console prints:

> 

Comment: `emptyString = ""` sets the value to the same value every iteration, so how would you know if it iterates more than once?

Comment: On a side note, you should iterate the `count` of `stringExample` in this case rather than each character.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that `emptyString = ""` is indeed run as many times as there are characters in `stringExample`. However, you misunderstood what `emptyString = ""` actually does.

**`emptyString = ""` sets the value of `emptyString` to `""`.** That's what the assignment operator "`=`" does. It doesn't care about what was in `emptyString` before. After this line, `emptyString` will have the value `""`. So it doesn't matter how many times you run `emptyString = ""`, at the end of the day, `emptyString` is still going to be `""`.

On the other hand, `+=` appends `""` to what's already in `emptyString`, and sets the result to `emptyString`.

By the way, a shorter way to do what you are trying to do is:

```
let beers = String(repeating: "", count: stringExample.count)
```

Answer (score -1):

add 
+= 
instead  = 
or write  emptyString = emptyString + ""

Comment: This is both confusing and does **not** solve the question.